# First part of IF statement is being ignored

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, vba

I have the following IF statement in VBA, but the "delete" part of the statement, or the bit before the ElseIf, is completely ignored:

```
    For i = 3 To (customerNum + 3)
    If Sheets("Reports").Range("L" & i).Value = "A" Then
        Sheets("Reports").Range("G" & i & ":M" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Sheets("Reports").Range("L" & i).Value <> "A" Then
        Sheets("Reports").Range("J" & i).Value = form1_1 & i & form1_2
        Sheets("Reports").Range("J" & i).NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yy"
        Sheets("Reports").Range("M" & i).Value = form2_1 & i & form2_2 & i
        Sheets("Reports").Range("M" & i).NumberFormat = "_-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    End If
Next i
```

The rest runs smoothly. No crashes or bugs.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "completely ignored" mean? Can you see the code enter the If block (where the Select + Delete is) in debug mode?

Comment: P.s. yours is a very basic "If" block, where either you enter the Delete part if the value of the cell L & i is equal to "A", or you enter the other part. So your statement "The Delete part is completely ignored, the rest runs smoothly" makes me just think that the cell "L & i" is never equal to A.

Comment: Perhaps the line `Sheets("Reports").Range("G" & i & ":M" & i).Select` isn't selecting anything.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks for the input, but that's the first thing I checked for. It's not the problem as "A" does indeed appear in the target block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not (!) supposed to be an additional answer. Yet, I would like to add this "answer" because (occasionally) I encountered the problem of various different "A"s or "C"s (etc.) in one Excel sheet. Working in large corporations I had colleagues working with multiple different character sets at a time (their native character set and the English one). Note that the cyrillic "A" `looks` like the latin "A". Yet, even with `Option Compare Text` the two are different. The following code will reveal the unicode of a character and might be a better way of checking if an "A" has been entered into a particular cell:

```
Public Sub CheckUnicode()
Dim lngRowNumber As Long

Debug.Print AscW("A")
With Sheets("Reports")
    For lngRowNumber = 1 To 100000
        If Trim(.Range("L" & lngRowNumber).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        Debug.Print AscW(Left(.Range("L" & lngRowNumber).Value2, 1))
    Next lngRowNumber
    ' The following will append a cyrillic a to the bottom of the sheet in Column "A"
    .Range("A" & lngRowNumber + 1).Value2 = ChrW(1072)
End With

End Sub
```

I am merely addition this "solution" for others who might encounter a similar problem. As mentioned before there are several characters which look alike but are not. Also note, that this is only the cyrillic alphabet. There might be other character sets out there which seem to look alike.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to start from the bottom then go up.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, nwrw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Reports")

    With sh

        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = Rws To 3 Step -1

            If .Cells(i, "L") = "A" Then .Range(.Cells(i, "G"), .Cells(i, "M")).Delete Shift:=xlUp

            If .Cells(i, "L") <> "A" Then

                .Cells(i, "J") = "something" & i & "something else"
                .Cells(i, "M") = "something" & i & "something else"

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's done it! May I ask what the logic is behind my statement not working and your "with" method?

Comment: The `with sh` is just so you are indicating what sheet you are referring to, instead of writing `Sheets("Reports")` on each line. I believe the main problem is that if you find "A" on L4 & L5, first you delete "A" in L4 and shift up,  L5 has shifted up now and becomes L4, so when you loop to L5 you have missed an "A" because it is now in L4. When you delete & shift cells, it is a good idea to start from the bottom, then you won't miss any cells going up. I also use filter a lot to delete the cells at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: That sounds like a better way of doing it. May I ask how it's done?

Comment: `Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row` then `For i = Rws To 3 Step -1` Counts the rows, then starts the loop from `Rws to 3`, `step -1` tells the code to go backwards, in this case it goes up a row. If there are 100 rows, the next row in the loop will be 99.